# Indentation marks for Python with Pygments TeX formatter

Tags: python, pygments, pygmentize

This is a followup of a [question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249755/8425) at [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) that got an answer at TeX level.

I use [pygments](http://pygments.org/) to typeset in TeX my Python code listings. I'd like to have some kind of L-shaped lines, like the ones I added in the image below to clearly exhibit the indentation level of every line of code.

Any ideas at pygments level? I guess I have to hack the TeX [formatter](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/) but I have no idea how to do it (and, to be honest, I'm running out of time for a book).

[image]